# Surface Integral - Better Parametrization?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

So I'm supposed to calculate

$$
\iint_S (x^2+y^2)dS
$$

Where $S$ Is the part of the plane $z=2x+2y-1$ which is inside the paraboloid $z=x^2 +y^2$.

The way I proceeded was to parametrize
$$
S:
\begin{cases}
x=1+r\cos(\theta),\\
 y=1+r\sin(\theta),\\
z=3+2r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))
\end{cases}
$$
where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and, since the circunference projected at the XY plane is centered at (1,1), we have $r \in [\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{3+2(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))}]$

Luckly, findind $||\vec{r}_{\theta}\times \vec{r}_r||$ wasn't so hard, and I found it to be $3r$.

**The problem is** the integral after that becomes painfully complicated (at least for me). I suspect there is a better solution/parametrization. Can somebody help me out?

Also, I know there is a way to do it using Stokes theorem, but I'm not suposed to use it on this one.